# Disable animation for page transition

Tags: animation, qooxdoo

How can I disable the animation proberty for page transition in qooxdoo mobile? When I call the `show()` method to display a page the default animation is "slide" but would like to have no animation at all. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 26.07.2014**

With qx > 4.0 you can set the animation option `null` by passing it with the `show` method:

```
page.show({"animation": null});
```

With qx <= 4.0 you can disable the animation for a page with the `showAnimation` property on the layout.

```
page.getLayoutParent().getLayout().setShowAnimation(false);
page.show();
page.getLayoutParent().getLayout().setShowAnimation(true);
```

Here a running example with qx 4.0:
http://tinyurl.com/lkrmv3m

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the "slide" animation on page transition. Changing the animation from "slide" to "cube" works fine but page.show({"animation": null}); seems to have no effect.

Comment: Which qx version do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 3.6

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The _page.show({"animation": null});_ works only with the current master on Github (qx > 4.0). I updated my answer.